# Using VSCode and CMake, how do I get CMake to recognize Eigen3Config.cmake installed through MSYS2?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, eigen, msys2

I'm trying to use CMake with VSCode. When I try to add Eigen3 into CMakeLists.txt and rebuild, I get this error:

```
[cmake] CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:4 (find_package):
[cmake]   Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen3" (requested
[cmake]   version 3.3) with any of the following names:
[cmake] 
[cmake]     Eigen3Config.cmake
[cmake]     eigen3-config.cmake
[cmake] 
[cmake]   Add the installation prefix of "Eigen3" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
[cmake]   "Eigen3_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen3"
[cmake]   provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
[cmake]   installed.
[cmake] 
[cmake] 
[cmake] -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Here is how my `Eigen3_DIR` is set. I've also tried setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the same:

```
Eigen3_DIR="/mingw64/share/eigen3/cmake"

$ ls /mingw64/share/eigen3/cmake
Eigen3Config.cmake  Eigen3ConfigVersion.cmake  Eigen3Targets.cmake  UseEigen3.cmake
```

I've also tried setting those environment variables to the `include` folder where Eigen was installed.

Here's the command VSCode is using:

```
[main] Building folder: GraphicsEngine 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --version
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" -E capabilities
[proc] Executing command: C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe -v
[main] Configuring project: GraphicsEngine 
[proc] Executing command: "C:\Program Files\CMake\bin\cmake.EXE" --no-warn-unused-cli -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Debug -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\gcc.exe -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -SG:/Documents/Projects/GraphicsEngine -Bg:/Documents/Projects/GraphicsEngine/build -G "MinGW Makefiles"
```

Here's my CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.0)
project (graphics_engine)

find_package (Eigen3 3.3 REQUIRED NO_MODULE)
add_executable (example Raytracer.cpp)
target_link_libraries (example Eigen3::Eigen)
```

The package I installed:

https://packages.msys2.org/package/mingw-w64-x86_64-eigen3

Is there something I'm missing or getting wrong?

Comment: You installed UCRT64 compiler, but MINGW64 Eigen, read the link for details. It would also help to install CMake from MSYS2 as well (either UCRT64 or MINGW64, depending on which one you're going to use).

Comment: Ah makes sense, thank you. Got it to work now using MINGW64.